# newly implemented condition statement throws unknown console error and breaks JS snake game

Tags: javascript

hey guys I'm following a tutorial on YouTube on how to make a snake game in JS. I'm implementing one function at a time. but when we got to an if condition that would check to see if the snake had made contact with the border; resulting in the game being stopped, the whole thing stopped working. The error I'm getting says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined". Here's my code. The if block towards the bottom is what's causing the problem. I commented it out so you can see it better.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#snake');
//sets the context of the canvas to 2 dimensions
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//create canvas unit
const box = 32;

//load image files
const ground = new Image();
ground.src = 'img/ground.png';
const foodImg = new Image();
foodImg.src = 'img/food.png';

//load audio files
let dead = new Audio();
let eat = new Audio();
let up = new Audio();
let down = new Audio();
let left = new Audio();
let right = new Audio();

dead.src='audio/dead.mp3';
eat.src='audio/eat.mp3';
left.src='audio/left.mp3';
up.src='audio/up.mp3';
down.src='audio/down.mp3';
right.src='audio/right.mp3';

//declare snake array
let snake = [];
//initialize snake array and put one object in the first index
snake[0] = {
    //create the x coordinate for one property
    x : 9 * box,
    y : 10 * box
    //and a y coordinate for the other, this will be the startin
};

//create the food

let food = {
    x : Math.floor(Math.random()*17+1) * box,
    y : Math.floor(Math.random()*15+3) * box
}

//create the score

let score = 0;

//control snake direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', direction);

//declare the global variable to hold the direction
let d;

function direction(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37 && d != 'RIGHT') {
        d = 'LEFT';
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 38 && d != 'DOWN') {
        d = 'UP';
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39 && d != 'LEFT') {
        d = 'RIGHT';
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 40 && d != 'UP') {
        d = 'DOWN';
    }
}

//draw the board
function draw() {
    //uses drawImage() method to draw background image to canvas
    ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);

    for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        //use ternary operator if current iteration is of index 0 - style = green else style =  white
        ctx.fillStyle = (i === 0)? 'green' : 'white';
        // fill with chosen color
        ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, box, box);
        // set stroke or outline to red
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        // draw outline
        ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, box, box);
    }
    //draw food image
    ctx.drawImage(foodImg, food.x, food.y);
    //draw score
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.font = '45px Orbitron';
    ctx.fillText(score, 2 * box, 1.6 * box);

    //old head position
    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;

    //move to chosen direction
    if(d == 'LEFT') snakeX -= box;
    if(d == 'UP') snakeY -= box;
    if(d == 'RIGHT') snakeX += box;
    if(d == 'DOWN') snakeY += box;

    //if snake its the food
    if(snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
        score++;
        food = {
           x : Math.floor(Math.random()*17+1) * box,
           y : Math.floor(Math.random()*15+3) * box 
        }
        //don't remove tail
    }
    else {
        //remove the tail
        snake.pop();
    }

    //create new head
    let newHead = {
        x : snakeX,
        y : snakeY
    }

    //check if game is over
     
    // if(snakeX < box || snakeX > 17 * box || snakeY < 3 * box || snakeY > 17 * box || collision(newHead, snake)) {
    //     clearInterval(game);
    // }

    //add new head
    snake.unshift(newHead);
}

let game = setInterval(draw, 100);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Snake Game</title>
        <style>
            canvas{
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <canvas id="snake" width="608" height="608"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please narrow this down to a [mcve], state the whole error with trace, and make it clear where the error is happening.

Comment: Where's the `collision()` function?